# redis json sql style query

Tags: php, json, redis

I have a bunch of json that I would like to store in Redis

```
{
    "foo": "37",
    "bar": "Alex",
    "baz": "Tom",
    "type": "test",
    "date": "12/12/2012 12:12:12
}
```

but coming from an sql background, I'm not too sure what the best way to go about doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "foo" = "37" AND "baz" = "test" ORDER BY date DESC
```

I've looked at hashes, but I'm unclear if Redis able to perform queries as the one above?

Comment: no You cannot search by field, cuz Redis stores data as key=>value where key is something like id or some hash and value is anything.
you can only get data by key. Redis is not RDBMS, Redis is NoSQL storage. recommend You to do that with MongoDB.

Comment: @num8er BTW, MongoDB is not an RDBMS and is NoSQL as well.

Comment: I know but it has methods to search in json datas.

Comment: I also know that I can make relations by storing this fields as key to get value that points to full json data in redis. But why to do that? Why to make it so comlex?

Answer (score 1):

The way to go about this with Redis is to build indices. For example, consider the following flow to "insert" your data into a hash key and build the proper indices:

```
HMSET somekeyname foo "37" bar "Alex" baz "Tom" type "test" date "12/12/2012 12:12:12"
SADD foo_index:37 somekeyname
SADD baz_index:test somekeyname
```

This will create a key called `somekeyname` of type HASH with the relevant data in it. Additionally, it will create/update two sets that we'll use as indices. Now, to get the keys that match your SQL select statement, do something like:

```
SINTER foo_index:37 baz_index:test
```

This will return to you any key names that fulfill the conditions. Sorting the results can be done at the client side or by replacing SINTER with SINTERSTORE and using Redis' SORT command on the destination key.